# Adding a class to an element which is not selected/focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a button, when it is hovered i want to add a CSS class to another element. However i have multiple elements and only want to add it to a specific one.

Currently i have :

```
  $("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>"); //Only shows drop down trigger when js is enabled (Adds empty span tag after ul.subnav*)


var button = $('#loginButton');

 button.hover(function (login) {
    $("ul.navbar-nav li span").addClass("subhover");
}, function () {    //On Hover Out
    $("ul.navbar-nav li span").removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
});
```

This works, however it adds the class to all the elements.

```
<li>

<a id="loginButton">
    <img class="IconStyle" src="Icons/loginIcon.ico"></img>
</a>
<ul class="subnav">
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<span class=""></span> // This is the element i want to add a class to.
```

The  is what i would like to add the class to, however as i said there are 5 of these created programmatically

Comment: So... select the element you _do_ want.

Comment: The elements are created programmatically, there are 5 of them and only want to select one of them.

Comment: If you add html code that'll help us to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Add a default id to that span

Comment: But it's created programmatically so would all the spans created then have the same id?

Comment: ohhh...then is it the first li in which the required span is ?

Comment: So you want to add class to which of these 5 spans? The first, the last or what???

Comment: thats it, so as i hover the login button, i want to add subhover to the span. But only that span, not all the others which are currently present

Comment: `That span` - is it in first li or second li or third li ?

Comment: That span wrapped in same LI as button??? Please, improve your question! BTW, i hope you know IDs must be unique

Comment: @A.Wolff just the span that is contained within the loginButton li

Comment: so: `$(this).closest('li').find('span').addClass("subhover")`

Comment: @Ani its the 4th but there maybe more in the future

Comment: I posted answer using toggleClass, more accurate in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `toggleClass` and `in/out` hover handler:

```
button.hover(function (login) {
    $(this).closest('li').find('span').toggleClass("subhover");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to:

```
<li>

<a id="loginButton">
    <img class="IconStyle" src="Icons/loginIcon.ico"></img>
</a>
<ul class="subnav">
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<span id = 'spanElement'></span>
```

and your JQuery to:

```
var button = $('#loginButton');
alert($("ul.navbar-nav li span").eq(1000000));
 button.hover(function (login) {
    $("#spanElement").addClass("subhover");
}, function () {    //On Hover Out
    $("#spanElement").removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
});
```

Comment: thanks but the <span> is created programatically, by :   $("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>"); //Only shows drop down trigger when js is enabled (Adds empty span tag after ul.subnav*)